# LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?

Tags: indentation, compiling, code

I'm looking for a LaTeX code sniffer and/or code beautifier, because I'm creating a CI server for my LaTeX books and I wanted a few things. :D

Comment: When you say "CI server", do you mean continuous integration?  Could you expand on that?  I find the question confusing.

Comment: `latexindent` is now a part of `TeXLive 2013`

Comment: I created a website that reformats the latex code to make indents correct.

http://c.albert-thompson.com/latex-pretty/

Answer (score 73):

> [`latexindent.pl`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexindent) is available on [`ctan`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) and is part of `texlive`
>
> See the documentation in [`pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexindent/documentation/latexindent.pdf) or [`html`](http://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/) for full details.

You can find (and follow) the project on `github` at

https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl

### basic usage

You can run `latexindent` from the command line by typing one of the following, depending on your operating system and tex distribution

```
latexindent myfile.tex
latexindent.pl myfile.tex
latexindent.exe myfile.tex
```

You can also run the script by using the [`arara`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara?lang=en) rule, `indent.yaml`.

### example 1: getting started

By default every time the script comes 
across `\begin{<something>}...end{<something>}` it will increase the indentation.

Starting with the following in `mwe.tex`

### `mwe.tex`

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        framed,
        width=\figurewidth,
        xmin=-5,xmax=5,
        ymin=-1,ymax=5,
        xtick={-6},
        ytick={-6},
     ]
      \addplot expression[domain=-4.5:2.2]{2^x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

and running

```
latexindent mwe.tex
```

gives the following output:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                framed,
                width=\figurewidth,
                xmin=-5,xmax=5,
                ymin=-1,ymax=5,
                xtick={-6},
                ytick={-6},
            ]
            \addplot expression[domain=-4.5:2.2]{2^x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

### example 2: align delimiters

`latexindent.pl` will aim to align delimiter-based environments; for example, starting with the following in `mwe.tex`

```
\begin{align*}
    F(-x) & =-(-x)^2 &   G(-x) & =-(-x)^4 & H(-x) & =-(-x)^6 \\ 
        & =-x^2    & & =-x^4    &       & =-x^6\\    
          &  =F(x)  &      & =G(x)    &       & =H(x)    
\end{align*}
```

and running

```
 latexindent.pl mwe.tex
```

gives

```
\begin{align*}
    F(-x) & =-(-x)^2 & G(-x) & =-(-x)^4 & H(-x) & =-(-x)^6 \\
          & =-x^2    &       & =-x^4    &       & =-x^6    \\
          & =F(x)    &       & =G(x)    &       & =H(x)
\end{align*}
```

### customising the indentation

All of the customisation is done by using the `YAML` interface. To get started, you might try creating the following small file

### `localSettings.yaml`

```
defaultIndent: "  "
```

and then run

```
    latexindent.pl -l mwe.tex
```

If you'd prefer to name the `YAML` file something else (say, `myfile.yaml`) then you can run

```
    latexindent.pl -l=myfile.yaml mwe.tex
```

### some further things to explore

The documentation in [`pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexindent/documentation/latexindent.pdf) or [`html`](http://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/) contains full details. Some things that you might like to explore:

- `verbatimEnvironments` for verbatim-based environments
- `specialBeginEnd` for your own patterns
- the `-m` switch which allows you to modify line breaks

### before using it on anything important...

I recommend both using the following:

- a visual check
- a check using `latexdiff inputfile.tex outputfile.tex`

Comment: Hi cmhughes, very interesting idea. But I get no difference in my source file and the resulting output. Indeed, when I run your script on `sampleBEFORE.tex` I still get no changes. (Perl ver. 5.12.4, running on OS X 10.8.1.)

Comment: Would you like updating the answer: informing the visitor that latexindent is part of TexLive. So users having TexLive can execute it directly without having to download from CTAN or following github readme.

Answer (score 19):

I created a website that reformats the latex code to make indents consistent. This uses [latexindent](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) in the backend.
This if a very rudimentary system but will do all simple indentation of items inside parentheses so they are at the same level.

It does not do any code sniffing, it also cannot detect if you have missing end tags.

https://c.albert-thompson.com/latex-pretty/

Comment: Works great! Thanks for providing this service.

Comment: Does your site use latexindent?

Comment: Yes It does use latexindent. I am working to implement all the features of the application.

Comment: @Whitecat I love your website and use it almost daily to reshape my code and fin my errors. One question, is it normal that it cannot be used sometimes (as if your site was off) . And then it comes back... Merci !

Comment: I need to make a more dedicated site as that one is hosted with some other word press sites which often get DDosed. I also made http://latexformat.com/ which looks more pretty.

Answer (score 14):

The closest thing to a LaTeX code sniffer is the [`nag`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nag) package which tries to detect and warn about usage of obsolete package and other things listed in [`l2tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu).

I'm not aware that a (La)TeX beautifier exists. LaTeX is a TeX format and TeX is a very dynamic language which allows to change its own parser rules during the compilation runs. This makes it very hard to process except by a full TeX compiler itself. I was thinking writing a limited tool using Perl a while ago, but never found the time to do so.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `nag` and `l2tabu`. +1

Answer (score 9):

There are several (very) simple code tidiers available.

Some come with editors (e.g. [Textmate](http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/basics/) has a LaTeX Tidy function) but I don't have an OS that can run this and it may just be the product below (see its edit history).

Some are written by users who needed one and wrote their own and have made it more widely available, e.g. Eric Tsu's [LateX Tidy](http://bfc.sfsu.edu/cgi-bin/hsu.pl?LaTeX_Tidy). I have used Eric Tsu's program a couple of times to reformat received LaTeX code as an aid to adapting it (to shorten lines, to remove redundant blank lines and to indent blocks (i.e. `\begin` environment) but, as with most products, I wouldn't use it to format code without subsequent detailed checking -- as it says on the website

> This is a little Perl script to neaten up the format of LaTeX files.
>
> This is simple and naive. This takes STDIN .tex files and prints to
>   STDOUT.
>
> Check your file! Backup! No guarantees!
>
> License
>
> This is released as Niceware, which is like the Perl Artistic
>   License, except you have to be nice to me when you criticize the code.

If you are looking for something more than tools like this let us know if you find it -- or end up writing it yourself.

Comment: Wrote one myself :)

Answer (score 1):

VSCode has an extension called [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) which autoformats your (latex) code. After installing it in the VSCode IDE, one can autoformat a `.tex` file by pressing:
`Ctrl+Shift+P`, `Format Document`, `<Press enter>`. (On mac replace `Ctrl` with `CMD`).

[image: Illustration]

You can try it out on a `.tex` file online on [their website](https://prettier.io/) before installing it.

## Note

I would be interested in seeing an example `.yml` that shows [how prettier can be included in(to GitLab) CI, as a check/test](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#list-different). Basically ensuring a build error is thrown if not all `.tex` files in a repository are `prettier` requirement compliant, and getting a build pass if the `.tex` files are formatted as `prettier` dictates. Please share a link to such explanation, or include it as a new answer, as I believe that may still be within the scope of the question.