# Source Code Indentation

Tags: indentation, sourcecode

I was wondering if it is possible to indent the code like in most programming languages as shown below:

```
\part
    \chapter
        \section
            \subsection    etc.
```

This would make the source code much more readable. So is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: possibly related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier

Comment: Whilst I think this is a bad idea in general, it could be useful for table or figure environments, and especially for TikZ.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Latexindent can do this

Comment: you can always(?) use `{` and `}` around stuff, so I use e.g. `\chapter{thechapter}{\section{section0}{…}\section{section1}{…}}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Spaces at the begin of source lines is always ignored by TeX. However, I disagree that it is more readable for a normal document. Having several paragraphs of a, say `\subsubsection` indented by many spaces is not really readable to me. 
Instead I normally add certain separation lines before the sectioning commands, like 80-120x `%`. You can use two or more of them for higher sectioning commands. Multiple chapters and parts should be not in one source file anyway, IMHO, but instead split over several files which are then included in the main document using `\include` or `\input`.

If you question is actually about *how* to do this *automatically* then note that this is of course editor dependent. I don't know any editor which does that for sectioning commands. It might be possible to configure the more advanced ones, but for that we would need to know which one you are using.

Comment: Is there a way to make the editor/front end do this by default because indenting every single line is a bit tedious; or maybe there is s front end/editor that supports this?

Comment: @SamanthaCatania you need to tell us what editor you use.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I run a mac; my personal favorite is texmaker but anything is fine (as long as it runs on a mac)

Comment: Not sure why this is the answer, the questioner asked about indentation which isn't the same as spaces. Also the questioner didn't ask for your opinion about something so subjective and personal as visual navigation. Please keep your answers on topic and relevant.

Answer (score 7):

Whether indenting "is possible" depends on the current category-code-régime and on the effects which you wish indenting to have.

Under usual category-code-régime indenting by means of spaces and/or by means of horizontal-tabs neither does affect the look of the text in the output-file (.pdf-file) nor does affect, e.g., the gathering of tokens for a macro-argument/for a `⟨balanced text⟩`/for the like.

Under unusual category-code-régimes indenting may affect the look of the text in the output-file and/or may affect the gathering of tokens for a macro-argument/for a  `⟨balanced text⟩`/for the like.
E.g., within the body of a `verbatim`- or `verbatim*`-environment indenting by means of spaces does affect the look of the text in the output-file. The environments `verbatim` and `verbatim*` switch to some unusual category-code-régime.

The story is as follows:

TeX's reading- and tokenizing-apparatus does read/process input line by line.

When preparing a line of input for tokenization, TeX will first convert the single characters of that line to have these characters fit its internal character representation scheme. With traditional TeX engines, the internal character representation scheme is the American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII). With LuaTeX-engines and XeTeX-engines, the internal character representation scheme is Unicode/utf8.
This yields that a character which in the input might be encoded in whatsoever way specified by the underlying computer-platform in use and which also has a representation in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme will TeX-internally be represented by the number of its code-point in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme.

Then—according to Donald E. Knuth's TeXbook—any space character at the end of that line will be removed. (At this stage, spaces will be represented by the TeX-internal character code 32 as 32 is the number of the code-point of the space-character in ASCII/in Unicode/in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme.)
*(With [Web2C-implementations](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/web2c.html) of TeX prior to the 2019 release of TeX Live, things deviate a bit from what is written in the TeXbook: With these implementations not only sequences of space-characters at the ends of lines will be removed but sequences consisting of space-characters and/or horizontal-tab-characters (code-point-number 9 in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme) at the ends of lines will be removed. See egreg's [answer/update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389084) to the question [Why doesn't a trailing tab typeset?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389030))*

Then a character will be attached at the end of the line whose code-point-number in the TeX-engine's internal *character representation scheme* equals the current value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`.
*(Usually the value of `\endlinechar` is 13(dec) and thus denotes the carriage-return-character as the carriage-return-character has code-point number 13 in ASCII/in Unicode/in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme.

Usually the category code assigned to TeX-internal character 13 (carriage-return) is 5 (end of line).  )*

Then TeX will start tokenizing the line.
I.e., TeX will "look" at the characters of the line of input in question and hereby take the content of the line of input in question for a set of instructions for putting so-called tokens into the token-stream.
Tokens can be control sequence tokens—they come in two flavors: control word tokens and control symbol tokens—or explicit character tokens.
*(A control word token is a control sequence token whose name consists either only of characters of category code 11 and/or of several characters. [Control word tokens with names consisting of mixtures of characters both of category code 11 (letter) and not of category code 11 can not be obtained by reading and tokenizing input but can only be obtained by creating them from other tokens via `\csname..\endcsname` / `\ifcsname..\endcsname`.]*
*A control symbol token is a control sequence token whose name consists of a single character whose category code is not 11(letter).*
*An explicit character token has two properties: A character code and a category. In TeX-jargon the character code of an explicit character token denotes the number of the code-point of the character in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme, which with traditional engines is ASCII and with XeTeX/LuaTeX-engines is Unicode whereof ASCII is a subset. In TeX-jargon the category of an explicit character token influences what the TeX-engine does when further processing that explicit character token: beginning/ending a group; entering/leaving math-mode; denoting an alignment-tab; denoting a macro-argument; denoting subscript or superscript; denoting a space; denoting some combination of glyphs of a font that shall occur in the output-file;...*
Categories are assigned to explicit character-tokens at the time of tokenization.
Which category is assigned to an explicit character token during tokenization depends on which category code the character in question has at the time of tokenization.
*E.g., when TeX is not about to gather the name of a control sequence token and in the input finds the character `A` (which at the time of preparing the line for tokenization was transformed to the TeX-internal character representation-scheme, either ASCII or Unicode, while, according to the ASCII/Unicode-standard, the codepoint of the character `A` has the number 65), it will insert an explicit character token into the token stream whose TeX-internal character code is 65 and— as usually category code 11 (letter) is assigned to character code 65—whose category is 11 (letter).

I used the term "explicit character token". There are implicit character tokens as well: This is when you do, e.g., `\let\foobar=A`. `\foobar` will be a control word token with the same meaning as the explicit character token whose TeX-internal character code is 65 and whose category is 11 (letter). You can use `\foobar` both for `\if`-comparisons and for `\ifcat`-comparisons as if it were the explicit character token `A` of TeX-internal character code 65 and category 11 (letter). But you, e.g., cannot use `\foobar` as an alphabetic constant.)*

When tokenizing the line of input, the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus of TeX can be in one of three states:

State S: Skipping blanks.

After tokenizing a control word token/after tokenizing a control sequence token whose name consists only of characters of category code 11 (letter), the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus is switched to state S (skipping blanks).

Both after tokenizing an explicit space-token (TeX-internal character code 32, category 10(space)—space has number 32 in ASCII/Unicode/in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme) and after tokenizing a control symbol token whose name consists of a character of category code 10(space) (e.g., after tokenizing a control-space, i.e., `\␣`, i.e., a control symbol whose name consists of a single character of TeX-internal character code 32), the reading apparatus will be switched to state S.

When the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus is in state S (skipping blanks), TeX will not take characters of category code 10 (space) from the input for directives for placing whatsoever tokens into the token stream but TeX will simply drop these characters, leaving the reading- and tokenizing apparatus in state S (skipping blanks).

When encountering a character of category code 5 (end of line) while in state S (skipping blanks), TeX will not insert any token into the token stream but will simply drop that character and will start processing the next line of input if present, thus dropping any information remaining on the current line of input and switching the reading- and tokenizing apparatus to state N (new line).

State M: Middle of line.

Both after tokenizing an explicit character token other than an explicit space-character-token (TeX-internal character code 32, category 10) and after tokenizing a control symbol token (a control sequence token whose name consists only of a single character of a category code differing from 11) other than control-space, the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus is switched to state M (middle of line).

When the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus is in state M (middle of line), TeX will take any character of category code 10 (space) from the input for the directive to place an explicit character token of TeX-internal character code 32 and category 10 (space) into the token stream. Then it will switch the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus to state S (skipping blanks).
Under usual category-code-régime both the space-character (code-point number 32 in ASCII/in Unicode/in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme) and the horizontal-tab-character (code-point number 9 in ASCII/in Unicode/in the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme) are of category code 10 (space). Thus under usual category-code-régime spaces and horizontal tabs are interchangeable/are treated in the same way.

When encountering a character of category code 5 (end of line) while in state M (middle of line), TeX will insert a space token, i.e., an explicit character token of TeX-internal character code 32 and category 10 (space) into the token stream and will start processing the next line of input, thus dropping any information remaining on the current line of input and switching the reading- and tokenizing apparatus to state N (new line).

State N: New line.

When TeX is about to start reading and tokenizing another line of input, the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus is switched to state N.

When the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus is in state N (new line), TeX will not take characters of category code 10 (space) from the input for directives for placing whatsoever tokens into the token stream but TeX will simply drop these characters, leaving the reading- and tokenizing apparatus in state N (new line).

When encountering a character of category code 5 (end of line) while in state N (new line), TeX will insert the control sequence token `\par` into the token stream and will start processing the next line of input if present, thus dropping any information remaining on the current line of input and switching the reading- and tokenizing apparatus to state N (new line).

What will be the effect of two consecutive line breaks in the TeX-input?

Due to the `\endlinechar`-thingie at the time of preparing the line of input in question for tokenization, there usually will be a character of TeX-internal character code 13 (13 = carriage-return in ASCII/Unicode/the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme) at the ending of each line of input while usually the category code assigned to internal character code 13 is 5 (end of line).

Two consecutive linebreaks usually means inserting TeX-internal character 13 (13=carriage-return in ASCII/Unicode/the TeX-engine's internal character representation scheme) both when encountering the first and when encountering the second line break while TeX-internal character 13 usually has category code 5 (end of line).

When processing the first of these two characters, the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus might be either in state S (skipping blanks) or in state M (middle of line). In the further case this character will, when the line in question gets tokenized, not yield insertion of a token into the token stream. In the latter case this character will, when the line in question gets tokenized, yield insertion of an explicit space token (TeX-internal character code 32, category 13) into the token stream. In any case the state of the reading-apparatus will be switched to state N after processing this character.

When processing the second of these two characters, the reading- and tokenizing-apparatus will in any case be in state N (new line). In this state this character yields insertion of the control word token `\par` into the token stream.

(As long as `\par` is not redefined processing `\par` in turn—beneath other things—yields cancellation of any horizontal glue at the end of the paragraph in question. Glue inserted due to an explicit space token which in turn might have come into being due to the `\endlinechar`-insertion-thingie in state M will be cancelled as well.)

This is how inserting two consecutive line breaks into the input usually yields ending the current paragraph.

---

**Summa summarum:**

Space characters (and with Web2C-implementations prior to 2019 horizontal-tab-characters as well) at the ends of lines will be removed by TeX at the time of preparing the lines of input for tokenization.

Space characters and horizontal-tab-characters at the beginnings of lines have no effect under usual category-code-régime:

When TeX is about to tokenize another line of input, the reading- and tokenizing apparatus is in state N (new line).

TeX converts spaces from the input so that they internally are represented by the TeX-internal character code 32.
TeX converts horizontal-tabs from the input so that they internally are represented by the TeX-internal character code 9.

Usually the category code 10 (space) is assigned to the TeX-internal character codes 32 and 9.

When TeX while being in state N (new line) during tokenization processes a character of category code 10 (space), it will simply drop that character, i.e., it will not place any token into the token stream and will remain in state N which determines the same treatment for consecutive spaces occurring in the input.

---

Within the environments `verbatim` and `verbatim*` a category code other than 10 (space) is assigned to the space character.

Within the `verbatim`-environment the category code 13 (active) is assigned to the space character and therefore in that environment tokenizing a space yields an explicit character token of TeX-internal character code 32 and category 13 (active). Character tokens of category 13 (active) can in many ways be used like control sequence tokens. I.e., within the `verbatim`-environment the space character will act as a macro. That macro in turn within the `verbatim`-environment (via `\let`-assignment) is defined to be equal to the macro `\@xobeysp` which in turn via `\leavevmode` ensures horizontal mode, via `\nobreak` prevents a line break and delivers `&nbsp;`, the control-space, which in horizontal mode leads to inserting whitespace/horizontal glue in the width of the glue inserted due to an explicit space token when spacefactor is 1000.

Within the `verbatim*`-environment with older LaTeX-releases (*I looked into a copy of "The LaTeX 2e Sources 2003/12/01 when writing the initial release of this answer)* the category code 12 (other) will be assigned to the space character (ASCII 32) and therefore in that environment tokenizing a space yields an explicit character token of TeX-internal character code 32 and category 12 (other).

Like with other character tokens of category 11(letter) and 12(other), TeX will insert glyphs of a font when processing an explicit character token of character code 32 and category 12 (other). The font used in `verbatim`- and `verbatim*`-environments is `\ttfamily`—typewriter-family, specified via the control-sequence `\verbatim@font`, usually "Computer Modern Typewriter" in OT1-font-encoding—while in the font "Computer Modern Typewriter" in OT1-font-encoding the glyph in slot 32 connected to the character token of TeX-internal character code 32 and category 12 (other) is this nice underscore-thingie `␣`.

Within the `verbatim*`-environment with newer LaTeX-releases *(I looked into a copy of "The LaTeX 2e Sources 2019-10-01 Patch level 2 when editing this answer)* the category code 13 (active) will be assigned to the space character (ASCII 32) and the active space still is let equal to `\@xobeysp` but `\@xobeysp` is redefined either (traditional tex/pdftex-engines) to be equal to `\asciispace`, a macro which delivers the glyph in slot 32 of the current font or (xetex/luatex-engines) to ensure horizontal mode and deliver the copy of a horizontal box of the width of the letter x in the current font (which should be the font for typesetting things verbatim, specified via `\verbatim@font`), containing the character from slot 32 of the  "Computer Modern Typewriter"-font in OT1-font-encoding. With xetex/luatex-engines it is ensured that redefining `\verbatim@font` for using another typewriter-font for verbatim-output does not break the visible-spaces-mechanism as here the box containing the things for a visible space is created by selecting the glyph in slot 32 after explicitly switching to "Computer Modern Typewriter"-font while it can be taken for ensured that the "Computer Modern Typewriter"-font contains the desired underscore-like visible-space glyph in slot 32.

Within the environments `verbatim` and `verbatim*` the category code of the horizontal-tab-character still is 10(space), thus within the environments `verbatim` and `verbatim*` you can use the horizontal-tab-character (↹) both for indenting the source-code in a way which does not affect the look of the output and for obtaining an invisible space of the with of horizontal-glue created by an explicit space-token:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
ABC
DEF
\end{verbatim}

\begin{verbatim}
	ABC
	DEF
	\end{verbatim}

\begin{verbatim*}
A B C
D E F
\end{verbatim*}

\begin{verbatim*}
	A B C
	D E F
	\end{verbatim*}

\begin{verbatim*}
A	B	C
D	E	F
\end{verbatim*}

\begin{verbatim*}
	A	B	C
	D	E	F
	\end{verbatim*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Of course my explanation of `verbatim` and `verbatim*` does just roughly outline how things work. In case you are interested in subtleties and details, feel free to study [The LaTeX 2ε Sources, File J: ltmiscen.dtx, section 1.3 Verbatim](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#subsection.36.1.3).*

Therefore under usual category-code-régime you can indent your code by means of spaces and/or horizontal-tabs as you like.

Within environments like `verbatim`/`verbatim*` that do switch to some unusual category-code-régime, you cannot indent your code by means of spaces as with these environments spaces at the beginnings of lines of input will be transformed into tokens that in turn yield visible output instead of just being skipped. Within `verbatim`/`verbatim*` indenting without visual effect is only possible by means of horizontal-tabs.

By the way:

Due to the removal of space-characters at line-endings at the time of preparing lines of input for tokenization, it is even with environments like `verbatim` and `verbatim*` (as defined in the LaTeX 2ε-kernel) not possible to produce output with visible spaces at the ends of lines.

I.e., the input *(␣ here denotes a space character)*

```
\begin{verbatim*}
␣␣␣\TeX␣is␣funny␣␣␣
␣␣␣\TeX␣is␣funny␣␣␣
\end{verbatim*}
```

does not yield the output *(␣ here denotes the open-box-glyph-thingie often used for providing a visible representation of spaces)*

␣␣␣\TeX␣is␣funny␣␣␣
␣␣␣\TeX␣is␣funny␣␣␣

but does yield the output *(␣ here denotes the open-box-glyph-thingie often used for providing a visible representation of spaces)*

␣␣␣\TeX␣is␣funny
␣␣␣\TeX␣is␣funny

An example exhibiting the aspects connected to deviating from the usual category-code-régime—all indenting is done by means of spaces only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{This is a section}

  \subsection{This is a a subsection}

  This is text that gets read and tokenized under normal category-code-r\'egime.
  This is text that gets read and tokenized under normal category-code-r\'egime.

  \begin{verbatim*}
  This is text that gets read and tokenized under verbatim's category-code-regime.
  This is text that gets read and tokenized under verbatim's category-code-regime.
  \end{verbatim*}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is an item that gets read and tokenized
          under normal category-code-r\'egime.
    \item \begin{verbatim*}
          This is an item that gets read and tokenized 
          under verbatim's category-code-regime.
          \end{verbatim*}
    \item This is another item that gets read and tokenized
          under normal category-code-r\'egime.
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Ulrich, thanks for this great answer! It clearly deserves more upvotes, even though it was probably way too scholarly and detailed for the OP. Your answer helped me understand why `\`X` followed by 〈one optional space〉 forms the 〈number〉 32 when X has been assigned category code 5 or 10 (in contrast to `\`\X` followed by 〈one optional space〉). I believe you may want to modify one or two things in your answer, though: 1) AFAICS, with both `verbatim*` and `\verb*` from the current LaTeX kernel, spaces have catcode 13, not 12. These spaces are `\let`-equal to `\@xobeysp`, ...

Comment: ... which in the end results either in `\char32` (pdfTeX) or in an `\hbox` of appropriate width containing `\hss` glue and the same `\char32` (after `\usefont{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}`; this is with XeTeX and LuaTeX). 2) With the non-starred forms (`verbatim` and `\verb`), spaces are active as you wrote, however what they yield is slightly more than a control space: ...

Comment: ... in that case, `\@xobeysp` is `\let`-equal to `\nobreakspace`, which leaves a `\penalty10000` (`\nobreak`) before the glue item from a control space. 3) (minor) The verbatim font defaults to `\normalfont\ttfamily`, however this is not hardcoded: what is actually used is `\verbatim@font`, which might be redefined by users.

Comment: @frougon Thank you for pointing out that things have changed. Now I did some edits after looking into a more recent release of source2e. ;-)

Comment: Dear Ulrich, you can add in your answer something related to the "tab" character, some users also use it to indent the code.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Done. ;-)

Comment: Master Ulrich: Thank you very much, it is always a pleasure to learn from your answers `:)`.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I am far from being a master ;-)  If I were a master my answers would not need so many edits. Besides this I regularly struggle with many things, e.g., output-routines and inserts ... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to make the editor/front end do this by default because
>   indenting every single line is a bit tedious; or maybe there is s
>   front end/editor that supports this?

[`latexindent.pl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en) can perform this indentation for you.

Let's say that you start with the following files, `myfile.tex` and `sam.yaml`:

### `myfile.tex`

```
 \part
part text
part text
part text
\chapter
chapter text
chapter text
chapter text
\section
section text
section text
section text
\subsection
subsection text
subsection text
subsection text
```

### `sam.yaml`

```
indentRules:
   part: "\t"
   chapter: "\t"
   section: "\t"
   subsection: "\t"
indentAfterHeadings:
    part:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 1
       level: 1
    chapter: 
       indentAfterThisHeading: 1
       level: 2
    section:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 1
       level: 3
    subsection:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 1
       level: 4
```

Upon running the following command

```
   latexindent.pl myfile.tex -l=sam.yaml -o=output.tex
```

then you will receive the following file:

`output.tex`

```
\part
    part text
    part text
    part text
    \chapter
        chapter text
        chapter text
        chapter text
        \section
            section text
            section text
            section text
            \subsection
                subsection text
                subsection text
                subsection text
```

This, and many other options, are detailed in the documentation, and are customizable through the YAML interface.

Answer (score 1):

In TeXstudio automatic indentation is enabled by default.