# Format LaTeX code in TexMaker

Tags: editors, texmaker

I'm doing a presentation using Beamer in TexMaker. The structure of the LaTeX source code is deeply nested and I need a way to format the code as in most programming IDE. Is this feature present in TexMaker or any other editor?

Comment: don't know about TeXmaker, but I wrote `indent.plx` for this task- I've detailed how to use it in [LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26102)

Comment: I saw this thread today, but I'm more interested to have it built-in the editor, than to run manually every time I want nice structure.

Comment: I found this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38618/source-code-indentation, but there is no answer and I'm more interested not in subsection formatting, but rather in frame, columns, items elements.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you’re looking for, i.e. what code looks like “in most programming IDEs”?

Comment: AFAIK, Texmaker already does some automatic tabbing when you hit Return key but not when doing stuff like tabular tabbing. As for setting color themes, you can click `Options > Configure Texmaker > Editor` and choose appropriate theme or modify the colors to your liking.

Comment: @damluar Was my answer any use?

Comment: @damluar Best way would be to submit a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) at TeXmaker Website for indentation with a link to cmhughes [ident.plx](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx) to give an idea. For a real programmer's experience switch to [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download) or [emacs with auctex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs).There are good commercial ones like [sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).User17670 makes a good point

Answer (score 1):

On the maker's website it says that you can 'collapse' the code of parts of a document. You could also create 'bookmarks' and label them as you wish, if tabbing blocks of text is not sufficient by itself.

Comment: I want to format latex code, to make it look nicer. Not to add a bookmark or tab a block.

Comment: Well, other than tabbing there's probably nothing you can you do.