# How align columns in a tabular environment?

Tags: tables, auctex

I want to align the source .tex file in order to reflect final table.

Here is the result of calling align-current on my tabular's content.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline  & {\em Execution Time (second)} \\ 
    \hline MPEG  & 123234                                             \\
    \hline MPEG with global reporting                     & 86987                                             
    \hline Gzip with all communication channels reporting & 86987         \\                                  
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Where am I wrong , Maybe in the auto-fill mode of my ~.emacs

```
;;; Auto fill to wrap long lines
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; No auto fill in some latex environments
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(defvar my-LaTeX-no-autofill-environments
  '("tikzpicture" "lstlisting" "tabular" "spreadtab")
  "A list of LaTeX environment names in which `auto-fill-mode' should be inhibited.")

(defun my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function ()
  "This function checks whether point is currently inside one of
the LaTeX environments listed in
`my-LaTeX-no-autofill-environments'. If so, it inhibits automatic
filling of the current paragraph."
  (let ((do-auto-fill t)
        (current-environment "")
        (level 0))
    (while (and do-auto-fill (not (string= current-environment "document")))
      (setq level (1+ level)
            current-environment (LaTeX-current-environment level)
            do-auto-fill (not (member current-environment my-LaTeX-no-autofill-environments))))
    (when do-auto-fill
      (do-auto-fill))))

(defun my-LaTeX-setup-auto-fill ()
  "This function turns on auto-fill-mode and sets the function
used to fill a paragraph to `my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function'."
  (auto-fill-mode)
  (setq auto-fill-function 'my-LaTeX-auto-fill-function))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-setup-auto-fill)
```

Comment: Related: [LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26102/5764)

Comment: Is the missing ``\\`` in the third row causing problems with the alignment algorithm?

Comment: I tested this as shown, without the missing `\\` and `align-current` does the job. I also evaluated your posted portion of your .emacs and it still works as expected. Does this happen in every file or only in this one?

Comment: Just in case others reach this question, the problem saw the font that wasn't a fixed width font. Changing to monofont for example, solved the issue.