# Automatic utility for tex source indentation

Tags: indentation, texshop

Is there any indentation tool for (la)tex?

I currently use TexShop under Mac OSX, so I can either use a TexShop plugin or a command line tool.

Comment: I just select the text I want indented and use `command ]` to indent, and `command [` to unindent. Not very automated, but does work, and that way I have control of what it looks like.

Comment: It shifts the entire block of text. I'm looking for a utility that can indent inner parts (e.g. subsections) more than their parents (e.g. sections).

Comment: What about Emacs? ;)

Comment: As you are typing after a section, just use `command ]` on the _first_ line, then all lines following will retain that indent (at least in `TeXShop`). Similarly if you are coming out of an indented block, use `command [`.  For text that already exist select the block you want to indent and apply `command ]`.  Any automated tool won't easily be able to work with custom environments or macros without some configuration set up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have a look to [latexindent.pl](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl). In my opinion an interesting tool. Have a look at  [LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier) for details.