# Auto-indentation of LaTeX Source code in TeXShop

Tags: indentation, texshop, sourcecode

Sometimes, I find it a bit hard to manually indent my code so that all the \begin{...}'s and \end{...}'s align vertically in my .tex source code.  In some code development environments, I know that there are options to auto-indent the beginnings and ends of loops, functions, and other code blocks. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in TeXShop or any other freeware for latex code?

Comment: related [Automatic utility for tex source indentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99602/15717) and [Indentation and line wraps in TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16510/15717)

Comment: and also [LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26102) I'm hoping to make an `arara` rule for `indent.plx` soon too :)