# Indenting style of LaTeX files with Sublime Text

Tags: indentation, sublime-text

Here is a part of my LaTeX code and what I want it to be:

```
...
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|X|X|X|X|}
...
```

However, if I re-indent it in Sublime Text 3, it becomes:

```
...
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|X|X|X|X|}
...
```

Then the folding function is also invalid, how do I fix this? I'm using `LaTeXTools`.

Comment: Use `latexindent`

Comment: which latex plug-in are you using?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Do you mean that is a command or a plug-in? Please be more specific. @HarishKumar

Comment: Refer to [LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71034) and https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl

Comment: By the way, `\begin{center}\begin{table}` is wrong.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `latexindent` isn't available directly as a Sublime Text 3 plugin, though right?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the plugin `latexindent`. Please see [here](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) for the documentation and the download.

Here is an example how to use it with `arara` and how the code looks after the indentation.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: indent: { overwrite : yes }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllXXXX}
        \toprule
        l & l & l & X & X & X & X \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 note that `latexindent.pl` is on `ctan` too :) http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent

Answer (score 1):

I found that [albertxing's gist](https://gist.github.com/albertxing/5298255#file-indentation-rules-tmpreferences) worked for me in ST3. To summarize, paste & save as LaTeX/Indentation Rules.tmPreferences in your user profile folder (Sublime's Preferences > Browse Packages > LatexTools). Restart Sublime, highlight all and Edit > Line > ReIndent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Indentation Rules</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.tex, sources.bib</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>decreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
                ^\s*\\end\{[^\{\}]+\}.*$
            |   ^\s*\\\].*$
            |   ^\s*\}.*
            |   ^\s*\%.*\(end\).*$
            </string>
            <key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
                ^\s*\\begin\{[^\{\}]+\}(\{.*\}|\[.*\])*$
            |   ^.*\\\[\s*$
            |   ^.*\\(.+)\{$
            |   ^\s*\\((sub)[0,2])?section(\*)?\{.*\}.*$
            </string>
        </dict>
        <key>uuid</key>
        <string>02EB44C6-9203-4F4C-BFCB-7E3360B12842</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Question. I go into my packages folder and I see LaTeXTools. Does this mean that I would use that folder, or create another folder called 'LaTeX' with a subfolder 'Indentation', and a file Rules.tmPreferences? I'm a complete beginner to Latex, I'm not even sure that I'm using the same plugin that will require this config file