# Automatic reformatting / style checking of input files?

Tags: formatting, sourcecode

Coming from Python land, one of the best tools is [`autopep8` and alike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770733/how-to-auto-reformat-python-code-and-solve-simple-code-conventions-breaks) which automatically tweak the layout and spacing of your programs to fit the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code style guide.

My basic question is: are there any similar tools/standards for LaTeX or similar functionalities in various IDEs that can automatically standardise my source-formatting and slap me around when I screw it up?

Comment: Tex doesn't really have code-formatting guidelines or strong layout conventions like other languages do. As far as I know, the answer to your question is no: no such tool exists.

Comment: You could use `latexindent`, but as @Jubobs said, not really any convention. For a few exceptions, you could print all in just one line.

Comment: There are some code tidiers. You could have a look at @mas Answer on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/

Comment: @Rico good stuff, looks like that just about answers my question, so I'll mark this as a dup. Cheers!