# How to fix TexShop editor textwidth to 80 symbols

Tags: editors, texshop

Hi i have to limit my tex-code to 80 symbols width. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: you'd need to insert hard breaks. IIRC this can be done by `Source->Wrap Code->Insert Breaks`. In TeXshop you'd write a macro that prettifies your source. other than that you'd need to switch editors. may I ask why you need to limit the linewidth?

Comment: a colleage asked me to do so because his screen is limited i we work together...
I think its good practice in coding anyhow...

Comment: there's a perl-script you can use to prettify your source, found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier
maybe it is helpful for your scenario.