# How can I beautify LaTeX code?

Tags: editors, code

Is there any shortcut (or something else) that beautify the code, like `ctrl+shift+f` does in Eclipse or `ctrl+k+d` in Visual Studio?

Comment: Well, shortcuts are features of specific tools. As LaTeX is a compiler not an editor, it does not has such a feature itself. It depends on your used editor (e.g. TeXWorks, etc.) or you can use an external tools. However, as (La)TeX is a "programming" language which allows to dynamically change syntax elements it is difficult to program such a tool. Some constructs, like verbatim text make it basically impossible.

Comment: I think the following answers your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26102/2975, making it a duplicate. In short: I recommend [latexindent](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent), which can be integrated as external tool by advanced editors/develop environments like Eclipse.

Comment: Why don't you just use eclipse for writing and compiling? Seems like the mist natural choice for you.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I think the mentioned Eclipse shortcut only works for C, C++, Java etc. I don't think Eclipse has a LaTeX formatter.