# How to edit/create table optimal in Latex?

Tags: tables, longtable, booktabs

I am familiar with some latex online editors like [tablesgenerator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#) ot [latex-tables](https://www.latex-tables.com/), however often I want to directly see the output in my own code, so I edit the tabular directly in my code.

Despite this, some functions and definitions in my preamble are not easy to implement in the online editors.

My problem is when the tables getting big with 20+ columns and lots of rows, editing and finding special cells becomes a big disadvantage.

I am looking for a way to format the table that the content is aligned with the columns. So the content of a column is directly oriented below each cell, I hope I explain this clearly.

This could be a reference:

[image]

However, using just the `tab-key`on may keyboard can order the contents, but when then editing one cell all contents in the row is being shifted and I have to start again.

Does someone have better solutions for this?

Comment: If the contents of a cell are rather large, you could use a new row for each cell.

Comment: Which editor do you use? TeXstudio has an "Align Columns" feature, for example.

Comment: @leandriis this can be godd i will try this. However as I am doing a concept matrix i have about 2.000 cells

Comment: @TivV right now i am using Kile for windows

Comment: any editor ought to be able to re-align the `&`  sources but if you really have 2000 cells you may prefer to use a spreadsheet interface, reading in a csv file from a spreadsheet as a latex tabular is easy enough. alternatively if it is a sparse matrix then don't use the `&&&\\ ` syntax but specify the cells by coordinate say `\cell{10}{5}{text}`  (which would require a bit of macro setup)

Comment: have you seen `latexindent.pl` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier? disclaimer: I'm the author

Comment: If you go for the external data file approach, you might want to check out the pgftplotstable package.