# Aligning the ampersands when creating latex tables

Tags: tables

Does anyone know how to quickly select all the ampersands representing one column and align them in overleaf (as can be seen in the picture below)?

Strictly speaking, this is not a LaTeX question, but an answer would help to create huge tables.

[image: ampersand alignment]

Comment: There is [`latexindent`](//ctan.org/pkg/latexindent); see ([LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71034/5764)) However, this is an external package.

Comment: Many TeX editors have a button for that. I'd expect Overleaf to provide this functionality too, but you should rather ask their support staff.