# Beautifier for auto indentation of tex source files

Tags: indentation, latexindent

Is there any software that can beautify tex files with proper indentation and spaces?
Something like C beautifier for C programs.

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: see `latexindent`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier :) project home : https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl